# How to append value_counts() values to new column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to count repeated values in a column(df1) and add it to a new dataframe(df2) with two modified columns. I tried with drop_duplicates(), value_counts() and assigned to new dataframe but value_counts() showing NaN values . How to convert dataframe from df1 to df2. Thank You.

```
df1:
    A       
0  Dell 
1  Lenovo
2  Acer
3  Apple
4  Lenovo
5  Dell


df2:
    A       B
0  Dell     2
1  Lenovo   2
2  Acer     1
3  Apple    1
```

Comment: Check second answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` on `A` column then apply `count` function on `A` column, name the count column as `B`.

```py
df_ = df.groupby("A").agg(B=pd.NamedAgg(column="A", aggfunc="count")).reset_index()
```

```
print(df_)

        A  B
0    Acer  1
1   Apple  1
2    Dell  2
3  Lenovo  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `.reset_index()` after `.value_counts()`:

```
print(df.value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={0: "B"}))
```

Prints:

```
        A  B
0    Dell  2
1  Lenovo  2
2    Acer  1
3   Apple  1
```